# APIGateway postToConnection not working from lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a websocket APIGateway. I keep track of connections in a DynamoDB table. I have an unrelated lambda in the same account that gets triggered from an SQS. This lambda reads the connection ids from the table and send messages via the APIGateway.

I am using the sample code to instantiate and send the message:

```
apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({apiVersion: '2018-11-29', endpoint: 'xxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test' });        
send = async (connectionId, data) => { await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionId, Data: `${data}` }).promise(); };
```

I do not see any error, nor is the message being sent. I have verified that the lambda has the required api-execute permissions. Verified that apigwManagementApi has been initialized with the right endpoint and also that the send is getting called. Verified in cloudwatch that there is no additional error from the APIGateway or from the lambda.

However, when I use the same code as part of a lambda proxied to the connect method of the APIGateway, it works and the message gets passed to the connectionId given. Also observed that the execute-api permission has never been accessed. So, I doubt if the call is even being made.

Is there any additional configuration that is needed for a lambda that is unrelated to the APIGateway(not proxied) to post messages to an APIGateway?

Comment: I am writing in python, and can post a message to the client using the special "@connections" url -- which is separate from the response to the route request, but I have not been able to post a message from the $connect route.  My post must be signed with SigV4Auth to work, could that be your issue?

Comment: Your code shows you creating a function called `send` but you're never actually calling it.  Did you leave this off in your example or did you actually forget to call `send()`?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue,it worked for me after resource based policies are added to the lambda.
sample connect policy :

```
"Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": XX,
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": XX,
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "XX/*/$connect"
        }
      }]
```